# Time to target with constant acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

I am writing a program to model space travel. I know my initial velocity, constant thrust, and the distance to the target. I am at some point in my acceleration burn and I need to know the time remaining before I need to begin my deceleration burn. Assume the ship is traveling in a straight line to the target.

Bonus points for giving the target an initial velocity. Super bonus points for giving the target a constant acceleration.

This is what I have so far, it seems to work. I wait until Tacc decreases to near zero, then flip and start the decel.

`double a0= ShipAccel;
        double v0= MyShip.vel.r1;
        double x1= Target.bearing.r1;
        //Tdec: Time to decelerate from current velocity to 0
        double Tdec= v0/ShipAccel;
        //Ddec: Distance traveled during deceleration.
        double Ddec= v0*Tdec - 0.5*a0*Tdec*Tdec;
        //Dacc: Distance remaining to continue accelerating.
        double Dacc= x1 - Ddec;
        //Tacc: Time required to cover Dacc
        //  Solve quadratic: t= (-v +- sqrt(v^2 + 2ax))/a
        double Tacc1= (-v0 + sqrt(v0*v0 + 2*a0*Dacc))/a0;  // +
        double Tacc2= (-v0 - sqrt(v0*v0 + 2*a0*Dacc))/a0;  // - disregard
        //Dacc1: Distance covered during Tacc (should equal Dacc above)
        double Dacc1= v0*Tacc1 + 0.5*a0*Tacc1*Tacc1;
        //Dtot: Total distance covered (Dacc+Ddec)
        double Dtot= Dacc1+Ddec;
        text.Print(L"%s: %e\r\n",Target.Name,x1);
        text.Print(L"Tacc: %e\r\n",Tacc1);
        text.Print(L"Ddec: %e\r\n",Ddec);
        if(Dtot > x1)
          text.Print(L"OVER\r\n");`

Comment: Is this 1D, 2D or 3D problem? Also is the thrust always tangent to the direction of travel, or can it be transverse also?

Comment: The overall model is 2D, but to keep this problem simple I am assuming a direct line to the target (1D). This is intended to be an avionics assist to the pilot, not a formal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Initial acceleration $a_0$, from time $0$ to time $t_1$, having initial velocity $v_0$
  $$\begin{align} v_1 & = v_0 + a_0 t_1 \\ x_1 & = v_0 t_1 + \frac{1}{2} a_0 t_1^2 \end{align} $$ where $v_1$ is the speed after the burn, and $x_1$ the position after the burn
- Constant speed $v_1$ travel from time $t_1$ to time $t_2$
  $$\begin{align} v_2 & = v_1  \\ x_2 & = x_1 + v_1 (t_2-t_1)  \end{align} $$
- Deceleration $a_2$, from time $t_2$ to time $t_3$
  $$ \begin{align}
    v_3 & = v_2 - a_2 (t_3-t_2) \\
    x_3 & = x_2 + v_2 (t_3-t_2) - \frac{1}{2} a_2 (t_3-t_2)^2
  \end{align}$$

Total time is $t_3$ (unknown). Use the burn times $t_{acc}=t_1$ and $t_{dec}=t_3-t_2$ above to get the govenring equations

$$\boxed{ \begin{aligned}
v_{T} & = v_0 + a_0 t_{acc} - a_2 t_{dec} \\
x_{T} & = v_0 t_3 + a_0 t_3 t_{acc} - \frac{1}{2} a_0 t_{acc}^2 -\frac{1}{2} a_2 t_{dec}^2 \end{aligned} }$$

where $x_T$ and $v_T$ are the target distance and speed at time $t_3$

Below are different scenarios. I assume the acceleration and decelleration is both done at the same rate of $a_0=a_2=g$

1. Fixed target at distance $x_3=x_T$ with zero speed $v_3=0$. Solve the distance equation for time
   $$   t_3  = \frac{g (t_{acc}^2+t_{dec}^2)+2 \,x_T}{2 ( v_0 + g\,t_{acc})} $$
2. Moving target at distance $x_3 = x_T - v_T t_3$ with speed $v_3=-v_T$.
   $$   t_3  = \frac{g (t_{acc}^2+t_{dec}^2)+2 \,x_T}{2 (v_T+ v_0 + g\,t_{acc})} $$

Comment: This is great! If I assume t1=t2, how do I find tacc?

Comment: So there is no cruise leg? Then $x_2=x_1$ as well as the speed $v_2=v_1$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not losing mass as part of the thrust, you're talking about motion with constant acceleration. Here is a list of equations that apply:

- $x=x_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$
- $v=v_0+at$
- $v^2-v_0^2=2a(x-x_0)$
- $x=x_0+\frac{1}{2}(v+v_0)$

Just solve for the variable you need in whichever equation is appropriate.

If you're losing mass as part of the thrust, your going to need to play around with the rocket equation. That's a much more involved process.

Comment: I need to solve for t, but I am having trouble figuring out x -- which depends on when I stop accelerating and begin decelerating. Plus, my initial velocity means the turn-around point is not the midpoint.

Comment: Well $x$ is just where you need to stop, $x_0$ is where you start, so $x-x_0$ is the distance to your target. If you need to calculate the acceleration and deceleration, just do it twice.